# I want to add frequency on base of position of ranking which their execution partially run not accurate - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, logic

I have conditional function which their execution not running as per business meet which to be require transformation as with desired result. This function contain ranking and frequency which are part of multidimensional array and their execution of sum on based of some calculation

I want to add frequency on base of position of ranking which their execution partially run not accurate. could you please help me out.

```
<?php
$arr = array (
    'AMXB 5321'  => array(
        array("course_title_code" => "AMB 5321",
              "content" => "Course",
              "total" => "303",
              "count" => "85",
              "ranking" => array(array(5),array(2,4,5)),
              "frequency" => array(array(5),array(1,2,11))),
        array("course_title_code" => "AMB 5321",
              "content" => "Succeed in the course",
              "total" => "300",
              "count" => "85",
              "ranking" => array(array(3,5),array(3,4,5)),
              "frequency" => array(array(1,4),array(1,2,11))
             )
    ));

array_walk($arr, function(&$v,$k){
    foreach($v as $key => &$s){
        $s['ranking'] = implode(',',range(1,5));
        foreach($s['frequency'] as $key => &$value){
            $temp   = $value;
            $value = (count($value) == 5) ? $value : array_merge(array_fill(0, 5 - count($value), 0), $temp);
            if($key == 1){
                for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
                    $value[$i] += $s['frequency'][$key-1][$i];
                } 
                $temFormat = implode(',',$s['frequency'][1]);
            } 
        }
        unset($s['frequency']); 
        $s['frequency'] = $temFormat;
    }
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Desired Result

```
Array
(
    [AMXB 5321] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [course_title_code] => AMB 5321
                    [content] => Course
                    [total] => 303
                    [count] => 85
                    [ranking] => 1,2,3,4,5
                    [frequency] => 0,1,0,2,16
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [course_title_code] => AMB 5321
                    [content] => Succeed in the course
                    [total] => 300
                    [count] => 85
                    [ranking] => 1,2,3,4,5
                    [frequency] => 0,0,2,2,15
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
function calRanking($ranks, $freqs) {
    $res = array_fill(0, 5, 0); // create array of 0
    foreach($ranks as $k => $v) {
        foreach(array_map(null, $v,  $freqs[$k]) as $e) {
            $res[$e[0]-1]+= $e[1]; //add the frequency according to rank key
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

foreach($a as &$v) { // for each calculate and implode 
    $v["frequency"] = implode(',', calRanking($v["ranking"], $v["frequency"]));
    $v["ranking"] = implode(',',range(1,5));
}
```

I assumed user with a lot of answer and reputation may build the question in more suite-able way for future learning...

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/K6fnT6)

Reference: [array-fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), [array-map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)